# Shouldn't multi-GPU mode be faster? with toy example

Tags: r, keras, gpu

I am trying 2 GPU model (both are Nvidia 2070 SUPER) on  ubuntu, but seems multi-GPU mode is indeed slower than single mode.

I tried many times with different depth. All gave the same result: Multi-GPU is slower.

Please advise where I go wrong? Or I am not setting the mode in right way?

If 2 GPU mode is slower, why bother? Or it is a single case?

references: I use model from ref-1, and setup multi-GPU mode with ref22

[1. mnist model for beginner](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/tutorials/beginners/)

[2. distributed strategy for keras](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/tutorials/advanced/distributed/distributed_training_with_keras/)

addtional remark:

1. when at multi-GPU mode, validation split is not allowed, here is the error msg I get `ValueError: validation_split argument is not supported with distribution strategies.`

here are the snapshot of `nvidia-smi pmon`

SINGLE-GPU MODE

[image: single GPU mode]

MULTI-GPU MODE

[image: both GPU are walking when fitting model2]

```
    library(keras)
    
    # setup distribution strategy
    # strategy$num_replicas_in_sync = 2
    strategy <- tf$distribute$MirroredStrategy()
    strategy$num_replicas_in_sync
    
    #setup the training data
    mnist <- dataset_mnist()
    mnist$train$x <- mnist$train$x/255
    mnist$test$x <- mnist$test$x/255
    
    
    #Multi-GPU mode
    with (strategy$scope(), {
      model2 <- keras_model_sequential() %>% 
        layer_flatten(input_shape = c(28, 28)) %>% 
        layer_dense(units = 128, activation = "relu") %>% 
        layer_dense(units = 128, activation = "relu") %>% 
        layer_dense(units = 128, activation = "relu") %>% 
        layer_dense(units = 128, activation = "relu") %>% 
        layer_dropout(0.2) %>% 
        layer_dense(units = 128, activation = "relu") %>% 
        layer_dense(units = 128, activation = "relu") %>% 
        layer_dense(units = 128, activation = "relu") %>% 
        layer_dense(units = 128, activation = "relu") %>% 
        layer_dropout(0.2) %>% 
        layer_dense(10, activation = "softmax")
      
      model2 %>% 
        compile(
          loss = "sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
          optimizer = "adam",
          metrics = "accuracy"
        )
    })
    
    #Single-GPU mode
      model1 <- keras_model_sequential() %>% 
        layer_flatten(input_shape = c(28, 28)) %>% 
        layer_dense(units = 128, activation = "relu") %>% 
        layer_dense(units = 128, activation = "relu") %>% 
        layer_dense(units = 128, activation = "relu") %>% 
        layer_dense(units = 128, activation = "relu") %>% 
        layer_dropout(0.2) %>% 
        layer_dense(units = 128, activation = "relu") %>% 
        layer_dense(units = 128, activation = "relu") %>% 
        layer_dense(units = 128, activation = "relu") %>% 
        layer_dense(units = 128, activation = "relu") %>% 
        layer_dropout(0.2) %>% 
        layer_dense(10, activation = "softmax")
      
      model1 %>% 
        compile(
          loss = "sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
          optimizer = "adam",
          metrics = "accuracy"
        )
    
    system.time(
      model1 %>% 
        fit(
          x = mnist$train$x, y = mnist$train$y,
          batch_size = 32,
          epochs = 5,
          verbose = 2
        )
    )
    
    #Epoch 1/5
    #60000/60000 - 13s - loss: 0.0698 - acc: 0.9821
    #Epoch 2/5
    #60000/60000 - 14s - loss: 0.0609 - acc: 0.9841
    #Epoch 3/5
    #60000/60000 - 14s - loss: 0.0582 - acc: 0.9855
    #Epoch 4/5
    #60000/60000 - 14s - loss: 0.0535 - acc: 0.9864
    #Epoch 5/5
    #60000/60000 - 14s - loss: 0.0457 - acc: 0.9882
    #   user  system elapsed 
    # 84.396   4.994  68.918 
    
    system.time(
      model2 %>% 
        fit(
          x = mnist$train$x, y = mnist$train$y, 
          batch_size = 32,
          epochs = 5,
          verbose = 2
        )
    )
    
    #Epoch 1/5
    #1875/1875 - 17s - loss: 0.0728 - acc: 0.9808
    #Epoch 2/5
    #1875/1875 - 17s - loss: 0.0628 - acc: 0.9840
    #Epoch 3/5
    #1875/1875 - 17s - loss: 0.0588 - acc: 0.9846
    #Epoch 4/5
    #1875/1875 - 17s - loss: 0.0523 - acc: 0.9867
    #Epoch 5/5
    #1875/1875 - 17s - loss: 0.0505 - acc: 0.9866
    #   user  system elapsed 
    #229.329  32.031  88.113
```

Comment: Multi-GPU only makes sense when you are bound by compute, which is not the case here. You don't need multiple GPUs to train an MNIST model.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy that makes sense. I will try with my real dataset and come back to share.